# Holomorphic functions in the disc $D(0,r)$ that satisfy certain properties

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $r>0.$ In each problem below, answer the question "Is there a holomorphic $f$ in $D(0,r)$ that satisfies the given condition for infinitely many  $n \in \mathbb{N}?$"

1. $f(\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{n^2}$
2. $f(\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{n^2-1}$
3. $|f(\frac{1}{n})| \le \frac{1}{2^n}$
4. $f(\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$

---

I have a hunch that the following theorem should be useful here, but I'm not sure how it should be used: if two holomorphic functions $f$ and $g$ on a domain $D$ agree on a set $S$ which has an accumulation point $c$ in $D$ then $f = g$ on $D$.

Comment: The problem needs restating. It should be, in each case, "Is there a holomorphic function $f$ such that ..."

Comment: @zhw. Yes, exactly. I've edited the question. I hope the statement is clearer now.

Comment: I'd say your hunch is right. What do you think the answer is for 1.? There's an obvious function that sends $\frac{1}{n}\mapsto\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: 1. @juan arroyo has given you the heads-up.

2. Think of it as $f(z) = \frac {1}{(1/z)^2-1}$ for certain values of $z.$
3. $f\equiv 0$ comes to mind. You'll have a more interesting problem if "nonconstant" is part of the requirement.
4. Think about $n$ odd.